# setTimeout send multiple forms 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to send the forms one by one. How can I do this?

how to make multiple forms more than 5 minutes one by one

I tried, but it was not successful

how to make shorter code

the code is getting too long I need to find out how to make it shorter

```js
<script>

function myfunction(){

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form1').submit();}, 10000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form2').submit();}, 20000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form1').submit();}, 30000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form2').submit();}, 40000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form1').submit();}, 50000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form2').submit();}, 60000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form1').submit();}, 70000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form2').submit();}, 80000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form1').submit();}, 90000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form2').submit();}, 100000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form1').submit();}, 110000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form2').submit();}, 120000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form1').submit();}, 130000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form2').submit();}, 140000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form1').submit();}, 150000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form2').submit();}, 160000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form1').submit();}, 170000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form2').submit();}, 180000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form1').submit();}, 190000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form2').submit();}, 200000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form1').submit();}, 210000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form2').submit();}, 220000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form1').submit();}, 230000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form2').submit();}, 240000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form1').submit();}, 250000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form2').submit();}, 260000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form1').submit();}, 270000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form2').submit();}, 280000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form1').submit();}, 290000);

setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('form2').submit();}, 300000);}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yas already said, setInterval is probably the function you should use, in your specific example it would basically look like this:

```
setInterval(function(){document.getElementById('form1').submit();},10000);
```

If you would also like to have the possibility to stop the Interval, you could code it like this:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){document.getElementById('form1').submit();},10000);

clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 0):

Window setInterval() Method may help to solve your problem.

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp